# Selenium Web driver and selenium RC

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-rc, webdriver

Is there a simple way i can convert my existing selenium RC scripts into the Webdriver format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way now to "convert" tests, but they can be tweaked to work with WebDriver using its [Selenium Emulation](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/SeleniumEmulation).

You should keep in mind that not all Selenium methods are implemented in WebDriverBackedSelenium. However in future releases of WebDriver the support should expand and at some point (probably when Selenium 2 will reach the Beta status) the Selenium and WebDriver will be merged so the transition will be easier