# merging selenium rc and webdriver

Tags: python, webdriver, selenium-rc, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

I have made most of my automation code using Selenium RC with Python. But, I feel that with the evolution in my product (what I'm testing through selenium RC), my automation needs are changed. I tried Wedriver with python and it works a treat with my product. But, as many features of my new product versions are inherited from the previous versions, I feel that I can make use of my existing Selenium RC code. But, for new features, I want to use Webdriver.

Moreover, there are also some things w.r.t the selenium profile that I 'm maintaining. Examples:

1. For ssl certificates, using selenium RC, I have 2 methods: Selenium profile (where I have saved the acceptance of ssl certificate) and `'trustallsslcertificates'` parameter while starting selenium rc. Using `trustallsslcertificates` slows down the automation speed like hell.
   But, using webdriver, I dont need all such ssl certificates.
2. Using Selenium RC, whenever I need to download a file using my web page, I have used the save option as default and saved it in the same selenium profile. But, using webdriver, I have other options to download a file, rather than maintaining the selenium profile.

I also checked in the existing question: [Selenium Web driver and selenium RC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342088/selenium-web-driver-and-selenium-rc), but, the answer seems to old, many things must have updated by then.

Crux of my question is: Can I integrate my existing python code, that I use using selenium RC (Python bindings - selenium.py ), with Webdriver using python ?

PS: Currently I am using selenium 2.3.0.jar file

Answer (score -1):

```
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium;


public class Facebook {

public static void main (String [] args)
{
    DefaultSelenium ds= new DefaultSelenium("localhost",1223,"*firefox","https://");
    ds.start();
    ds.windowMaximize();
    ds.open("www.facebook.com");

}
}
```

Comment: Can you please edit the code and add comments to explain what part of this code is being used to merge the calls to rc through webdriver ?